# Display loader before form submits in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, loader

I currently have a login form as displayed below:

```
+----------------------------------+
|                                  |
|           +----------+           |
|           | E:       |           |
|           | P:       |           |
|           | SUBMIT   |           |
|           +----------+           |
|             LOADER               |
|                                  |
+----------------------------------+
```

Form Definition:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post))
      {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <form action="" id="test">
```

My submit button is displayed as below:

```
   <div>
       <input type="submit" value="Log in" onclick="OpenSite();" />
       <a>@Html.ActionLink("Forgot your password?","ForgotPassword","Account")</a>
   </div>
```

Loader:

```
   <div class="loader" id="myLoader" style="display:none">Loading...</div>
```

With an 'OpenSite' function:

```
<script>
    function OpenSite() {

        $('.loader').show();
        $('#openPopup').click();
    };
</script>
```

How can i force this function to execute before the form is submitted, but when I press the '`Submit`' button?

I.e:

```
+---------------+
 User Fills form
+---------------+
       ||
       \/
+---------------+
  User Presses 
     submit
+---------------+
       ||
       \/
+---------------+
 Display loader
+---------------+
       ||
       \/
+---------------+
  Display popup
+---------------+ 
       ||
       \/
+---------------+
  Submit form 
  to controller
+---------------+
```

This means that the 'loading' animation will display while the next page is loading.

How can this be achieved?

I tried adding an `alert("hello world");` to the start of the function, and it executed but my loader didn't display at all :(

Any help would be much appreciated.

I have also tried:

```
$("#test").submit(function (event) {
    $('#myLoader').show();
});
```

with no luck

Comment: Have you tried showing it in the form submit event?

Comment: just like @filur suggested, you need to use the "onsubmit" event

Comment: Have already tried that, with zero success.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the default action of the form so it doesn't submit before you want it to like so:

```
 $('#formid').on('submit',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault() // stops normal submit action
   //make loading div visible, set it to absolute position in middle of page  and just make it display: block; or something
   //do submit action stuff here, i.e. ajax stuff

})
```

EDIT: Apologies it wasn't on `'click'` but on `'submit'` that catches both clicking submit and pressing enter to submit.

Comment: there's a few issues with this, the main one being that user could also press 'enter' and the form would be submitted, bypassing this altogether.

Comment: pressing enter to submit is the same as clicking submit so it catches pressing enter as well. I know it does this as I use this for my own stuff and it works with pressing enter without any code changes so I know it works.

Answer (score 0):

I hate answering my own questions, but in order for a 'workaround', i've had to use inline code:

Using:

```
<input type="submit" value="Log in" onclick="$('#myLoader').show(); alert('hello');" />
```

Will both show the loader, followed by an alert.

I think the issue here was with the loader being animated, it itself was taking too long to show before the actual page was submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever submitting a form, and you want to make changes to the normal submit functionality, use the onSubmit functionality as Thermatix suggests. The trick to this problem is that you want it to submit in addition to other stuff, so remove the inline stuff and try this:

```
$('#formID').on('submit',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault() // stops normal submit action

   $('#myLoader').show();
   // anything else you want to do while still on this page

   $('#formID').submit();
});
```

You may also be running into the 'issue' of the form being submitted so quickly that the .show() event isn't visible to the human eye. If you want to test whether this code is working, just comment out `$('#formID').submit();` You should see the "Loading..." show up. Once you've confirmed it's working, uncomment the form.submit line and you should be golden.

Another sanity check: make sure this code either exists in the `<head>` or in a `<script>` tag at the bottom of the page. This makes sure that JS sees the DOM elements this function is attaching to.